# Extending the Windows Task Scheduler log file

Tags: windows-server-2003, log-files, scheduled-task

The windows task scheduler logs the results of each task run in a file named Schedlgu.txt in the windows directory.

This file is automatically rotated when it reaches a certain size. Is there any way to extend this to a larger file size, since I have a server with so many tasks running that I only have around 30 minutes worth of logging available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\SchedulingAgent\MaxLogSizeKB DWord value