# How to display more Task Scheduler logs?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, logging, task-scheduler

Under a Windows Server 2012 R2, I see less than 2 days of Task Scheduler logs ! To be honest that's already 17'295 entries, maybe is it the maximum capacity ?

Therefore my question : is the problem due to display options, or is the server keeping so little logs ? In the second case, how to extend logging capacities ?

To view the logs I go to Event viewer > Apps and services > Microsoft > Windows > Task Scheduler > Operational

Any help would be appreciated.

P. S. I found an older discussion which doesn't seem to apply for Windows Server 2012 R2 : [Extending the Windows Task Scheduler log file](https://serverfault.com/questions/102230/extending-the-windows-task-scheduler-log-file)

Answer (score 6):

Woaw, I found the solution myself :

1. In Event Viewer, when the logs are displayed, click on "Properties" the right panel
2. There you have an option "Max Logs (KB) :" where you can set the maximal size of your logs. By default it seems to be 10 MB (10'000 KB), just increase it !

I will validate this answer if the solution works.

Comment: Anf FYI the logs are now located under %SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\